# C++ What's the best way to end this 8-Bit for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, simplify

Is it possible to write this for loop shorter or more elegant without using *uint16_t*? There is an overflow when *i* reaches *0xFF*.

```
for (uint8_t i = 0; i <= 0xFF; i++)
{
    // do something
    if (i == 0xFF)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Remove the whole `if`. It’s redundant.

Comment: `i = 0; do { .... } while (++i);`

Comment: Removing the if changes this into an infinite loop.

Comment: No it isn't! When i is 0xFF and the loop is over i gets an overflow and is again at 0.

Comment: a do...while seems exactly like what you want.

Comment: @n.m.: Nice! IMHO it would deserve to be an answer...

Comment: But seriously, just use `int` (not any other type).

Comment: do-while looks pretty good. I forgot about the pre increment. I'm trying to minimize the size of my code to us it with a microcontroller.

Comment: Are you sure microcontroller has 8bit registers? Otherwise you just make things worse by not using `int`

Comment: A small simplification:

    `for (uint8_t i = 0; ; ++i) {
        /* do stuff... */
        if (i == 0xFF)
            break;
    }`

Comment: Beware, some bit operations are undefined for signed *int*eger types.

Answer (score 4):

As overflow for unsigned numbers are well-defined, this loop can do it:

```
uint8_t i = 0;
do {
    // use i here
    i++;
} while (i);
```

*i* overflows (becomes 0) at the 256th iteration and the while stops because the condition is false.

Note: this trick is only worth it, if you are on a <32-bit platform. On >=32-bit platforms, there is a high chance that this trick is transformed into a loop which uses >=32-bit wide counter.

On the other hand, on 8-bit platforms, I think this is the most efficient and smallest 256-iteration loop.

Comment: Please always comment heavily how and why this works! [Principle of Least Astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)

Comment: While neat and all, that it's weird-looking means it ought to be better than the alternatives.  Still, to see how g++ compared your code to the code in my loop, it was interesting to see that it was 100% identical asm for both solutions.  https://godbolt.org/g/ec8RFf   You could do ++i in your condition to get rid of the in-body loop management code.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis: :) yep, that's why I put the note in the answer. And even for 8-bit targets, they could compile to the same asm with good compilers.  Basically, our solutions are the same. I've just added mine, because it doesn't have a 0xff constant. I've put `i++;` into the loop intentionally, because I don't really like modifying the loop variable in the condition itself, it is clearer in my opinion. But it has drawbacks too: if there is a `continue` statement in the loop, so it is really a matter of preference. It's a pity that we don't have backward tested `for` loops :)

Answer (score 1):

Not the shortest, but the coolest way to do this is to declare an array with all possible values of `uint8_t` and iterate over it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

namespace detail {
template<typename int_t, int_t cnt, bool not_done, int_t... rest>
struct range_impl {
    static constexpr auto& value = range_impl<int_t, cnt - 1,
        (cnt - 1) != std::numeric_limits<int_t>::min(), cnt, rest...>::value;
};

template<typename int_t, int_t cnt, int_t... rest>
struct range_impl<int_t, cnt, false, rest...> {
    static constexpr int_t value[] = { cnt, rest... };
};

template<typename int_t, int_t cnt, int_t... rest>
constexpr int_t range_impl<int_t, cnt, false, rest...>::value[];
} // detail

template<typename int_t>
struct range : public detail::range_impl<int_t, std::numeric_limits<int_t>::max(), true> {};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for(uint8_t i: range<uint8_t>::value) {
        std::cout <<  (int) i << std::endl;
    }

    for(int8_t i: range<int8_t>::value) {
        std::cout <<  (int) i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The `range` struct generates the array in compile time. This code can be used for any integer type.

Comment: Isn't that way to oversized?